# Which Amazon Web Services to use

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, icloud, cloudkit, amazon-cognito

I currently am running my app on CloudKit by Apple. I would like to start using Amazon Web Services instead but I am not sure which part I should be using.
The app currently allows the user to log in on multiple devices and save a  date value.
It then allows all of the user to fetch the same images and strings from CloudKit.

Should I be using AWS Cognito or S3 or something else?
Are there any tutorials for this?
Thank you

Comment: Without knowing more about your app: Cognito for identity and device state synchronization, S3 for image storage, and S3 (or conceivably DynamoDB) for string storage.

Comment: You should start at: https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/ They just released a new toolkit / environment for mobile development

Comment: Great. I will take a look. Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to link the content to the user that created it but also allow other users to view that content as well? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can create roles which allows the write access for the user who created it and read only access to all other users in the identity pool. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/concepts/iam-roles/ for more details.

Comment: Why do you want to move the backend from CloudKit to AWS?

Comment: I have unfortunately had an inconsistent experience when using CloudKit to store the data. Sometimes the data just  won't download from the Servers, sometimes causing the app to be rejected then once they review the same app and binary again it goes through. It is fantastic when it works but unfortunately inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Amazon Cognito](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) for authenticating and identifying your users and delivering AWS Credentials to your users' devices. These AWS Credentials enable your users to securely access your AWS Resources. See [How Amazon Cognito Keeps Mobile App Users' Data Safe](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2XEKZCNBM7U64/How-Amazon-Cognito-Keeps-Mobile-App-Users-Data-Safe).

Amazon Cognito also provides [data synchronization capabilities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/sync/) that enable you to save user-specific information that only the current user can read. Look at [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) for storing application-wide data that is shared with all users (like CloudKit database/records). [Cognito also integrates with DynamoDB to enable fine-grained access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/concepts/iam-roles/#fine-grained-access-to-amazon-dynamodb) that might be interesting for you to review too. Use [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for storing large objects (like CloudKit "Assets") like images or other files.